# Помогите с пунктуацией в предложении: правильно ли расставлены запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

Они вырабатывают их специально, особым образом и у каждого они, как правило, отличаются.

Answer (score 1):

*Они вырабатывают их специально, особым образом, и у каждого они, как правило, отличаются.*

"Как правило" - вне обсуждения: вводное.

После "специально" (очень специфическое употребление слова в этом предложении) запятая перед

а) уточнением (а именно: особым образом), и тогда это уточнение нужно запятой же и закрыть;

б) однородным членом предложения (и тогда запятая как бы и не нужна, но

в) у нас же две основы - они вырабатывают; они отличаются, - это разные "они": ССП, вторые "они" - это "их" из первой части.

---

Пы.Сы. Чем дольше читаю и толкую предложение, тем меньше его понимаю. Вырабатывать можно характер, как Алёша Птицын (кино), а некие поделки - обрабатывают...